# Display pyqtgraph with no margins [SOLVED]

Tags: pyqtgraph, pyqt6

When I display a pyqtgraph with axes hidden, there is a margin on the left and right of the display and smaller one top and bottom:

[image]

How can I get rid of those margins? The `contentsMargins` and `viewportMargins` are all zero.

Minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import numpy as np

from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
import pyqtgraph as pg


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setFixedSize(600, 200)
        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.graphWidget.hideAxis("bottom")
        self.graphWidget.hideAxis("left")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

        data = np.random.normal(size=1000)
        self.graphWidget.plot(data)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main = MainWindow()
main.show()
app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for spaces around your data is that autorange is using default padding of `0.2`. Each time plot is rendered and autoranged, there is some empty space around it.

You can set default autorange padding to 0 by using `self.graphWidget.setDefaultPadding(0)`.

Have a look at [documentation](https://pyqtgraph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference/graphicsItems/viewbox.html#pyqtgraph.ViewBox.setDefaultPadding).